# Displaying both Traditional and Simplified Chinese in Java

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization

Is it possible to draw both Traditional and Simplified Chinese characters in the same Java application with logical fonts like "SansSerif"? I only get the traditional variety with CJK codepoints.

I've tried setting Locale.setDefault() and GraphicsEnvironment.preferLocaleFonts() before creating the font. I've tried using -Duser.language and -Duser.country on the command line when starting java.exe. Also tried creating the font with AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute.LANGUAGE set on it. No effect.

I'm not using Swing or AWT. Just trying to draw into an off-screen BufferedImage. I'm on Windows 7 and I verified I have fonts installed that support Traditional and Simplified Chinese (MingLiU and SimSun). I also checked Java's font configuration file, and I see both of those fonts listed there.

What else should I be doing?

Comment: any use case where you need to show traditional & simplified Chinese text at the same component?

Comment: I want to let users switch languages on the fly without restarting the application. Also, the names of available languages in the list are written in their native script, so I want those to display properly as well.

Comment: In your case, I would suggest you to set the font and text for rendering your text. First you render with one font, then with the other one. Would it work?

Comment: Well, if I select the font by physical name it will probably work, but then I have to know ahead of time the font names for all supported platforms. I was hoping to let Java automatically select the font for me through it's [logical font](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#desktop-rendering).

Comment: The problem is that Java strings consist of 16-bit Unicode characters and the rendering of Chinese characters depends on the font since there is no differentiation of Traditional and Simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display both Simplified and Traditional Chinese text in Java, so long as you have a font that includes both sets of characters.

I wrote this brief program to demonstrate:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ChineseFonts {

    public static final int GAP = 35;
    public static final int FONTS_PER_LINE = 2;

    public ChineseFonts(String s) {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage((int) Math.ceil(rect.getWidth()), (int) Math.ceil(rect.getHeight()), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        String title = "Chinese Fonts on " + System.getProperty("os.name") + ", version " + System.getProperty("os.version");
        int fontY = 30;
        printString(title, graphics, 0, fontY, new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 28), false);
        fontY += GAP + 10;
        int counter = 0;
        for (String fontName : new String[]{Font.MONOSPACED, Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.SERIF}) {
            Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 24);
            printString(s, graphics, counter++, fontY, font, true);
            if (counter % FONTS_PER_LINE == 0)
                fontY += GAP;
        }
        Font[] localFonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        List<Font> chineseFonts = new ArrayList<Font>();
        String simplifiedAndTraditionalChinese = "????";
        for (int j = 0; j < localFonts.length; j++) {
            if (localFonts[j].canDisplayUpTo(simplifiedAndTraditionalChinese) == -1) {
                chineseFonts.add(localFonts[j].deriveFont(24F));
            }
        }
        for (Font font : chineseFonts) {
            printString(s, graphics, counter++, fontY, font, true);
            if (counter % FONTS_PER_LINE == 0)
                fontY += GAP;
        }
        graphics.dispose();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("chineseFonts.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    private void printString(String s, Graphics graphics, int counter, int y, Font font, boolean showFontDetails) {
        graphics.setFont(font);
        if (showFontDetails)
            s = font.getFamily() + " " + s;
        graphics.drawString(s, 20 + (counter % FONTS_PER_LINE) * 510, y);
        if (showFontDetails)
            System.out.println("Printing " + s + " using " + font.getName() + ", which is " + font.getFontName() + " in family " + font.getFamily());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ChineseFonts("S: 漢字 T: 汉字");
    }
}
```

The 2 simplified and 2 traditional Chinese characters used are from the wikipedia page on Chinese Characters. When you run it, all the fonts used are printed to stdout, and the image is output with the font names and the Chinese characters.

Here are the 3 logical fonts and the first physical font that worked:

- Monospaced
- SansSerif
- Serif
- Arial Unicode MS S

Comment: In many cases the same Unicode code point has different glyphs in Traditional and Simplified Chinese (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language_dependent_characters). There are ways to store in OpenType fonts language-specific glyphs, but you would have to be able to tell the font rendered "use the Traditional Chinese glyphs", and Java can't do that.

Comment: That's not what was asked. The question was whether it was possible to use a logical font in Java to display both simplified and traditional Chinese characters. Where users won't accept the unified glyph for a codepoint that has variant aliased glyphs in different languages, the user can configure Java's font.properties to select a better physical font for their preferred language. There are several good free Chinese fonts available.

Comment: to Colm: my comment is for this answer, not for the question. And specifically "you have a font that includes both sets of characters"